# How to create custom sort and save it

Tags: php, laravel

I have `order_by` column in News model. I have some oder in that like 1,2,3 etc,
Now I am trying to do that user drag and drop news and it get updated in the order_by column inside `news_info` table.
Ordering should be like if I move fifth news to the first then first goes to second and second goes to third.

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Entities;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * This is for storing  news
 * Class News
 * @package Modules\Newsletter\Entities
 */
class News extends Model {

    use WorkflowTrait;
    protected $table = 'news_info';
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'header', 'description', 'status', 'created_by', 'media_url', 'media_thumbnail', 'media_type','order_by'
    ];
}
```

What I tried is-

```
public function customSorting($old,$new){
    for ($i=$old;$i<$new;$i++){
       $inc = $i + 1;
       $newOder = News::where('order_by',$i)->first();
       $result =  $newOder->update(['order_by' =>$inc]);
    }
}
```

But this not giving the result which I want.
Can please anyone help me in this.
Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update all the tables to increment the `order_by` by 1, where the `order_by` field is equal to or higher than the one you are setting on your new model, and where `order_by` is less than its current value.

Something like,

```php
$news = News::find(1); // Whichever model you are updating

$newOrderBy = 1; // The new order_by value 
$oldOrderBy = $news->order_by;

// Update rows that should be incremented by 1
News::where('order_by', '>=', $newOrderBy)
    ->where('order_by', '<', $oldOrderBy);
    ->update([
        'order_by' => DB::raw('order_by + 1'),
    ]);
// Set the new orderby on current model
$news->update([
    'order_by' => $newOrderBy,
]);
```

Comment: Can you please make me understand what it mean by Update all the tables to increment the order_by by 1.

Comment: @RaviPratapSingh What Qirel means is that when a news article is reordered, you save that new `order_by` in your `news_info` table then increase each `order_by` value for the `news_info` records which have a greater `order_by` value by `1` effectively moving them down.